# Magento 2 : Separate Invoice for Each Item in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, invoice

After placing order we have option to create invoice automatically. That is a single invoice with all items. Instead of having all items in a single invoice i want to have separate invoice for each item. Your suggestion are welcome.

I tried to find in admin if we have this option. Basically i want that after placing order a separate  invoice is created for each ordered item and email to customer in a single pdf.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any admin option for this functionality. You would need to find an extension that does this, or create a custom extension that extends vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Invoice to behave as expected.